# Counting the number of equations in models with connectors

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am currently evaluating Dymola 2020 to build a solar power plant model, but I struggle with the number of equations in models which use a custom connector.

Here is the code:

```
connector Port
  flow Real Q;
  Real P;
  Real T;
end Port;
```

```
model Inlet
  parameter Real Q = 1;
  parameter Real P = 2;
  parameter Real T = 3;
  Port a;
equation 
  a.Q = Q;
  a.P = P;
  a.T = T;
end Inlet;
```

I set 3 equations in the model, but there is an error showing there are 4 equations. How are the equations counted? Why are there 4 of them?

> The problem is structurally singular.
>
> It has 3 scalar unknowns and 4 scalar equations. The Real part has 3
>   unknowns and 4 equations. The Integer part has 0 unknowns and 0
>   equations. The Boolean part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations. The String
>   part has 0 unknowns and 0 equations.
>
> The number of scalar Real unknown elements are 3. The number of scalar
>   Real equation elements are 4.
>
> Part of the problem for Real elements is overdetermined. There are 1
>   scalar equations too many in the set: a.T = T; a.P = P; a.Q = Q;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separated problems with your example:

1. Connectors usually contain **pairs** of across/potential and flow/through variables [Modelica Language Specification](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf), Section 9.3.1. Following this convention, the models using these connectors usually define a relation between flow and across variables. For some general - and very readable - information on the definition of connectors see [Modelica by Exmple](https://mbe.modelica.university/components/connectors/connector_def/). I think it is not mandatory to follow this convention, but it will make life a lot easier if you do so when modeling physical systems.
2. The `Inlet` sets all interface variables. Physical source models set either the across or the flow variable. You have a source of pressure **or** a source of flow, it cannot set both. This comes down to a pipe computing either a pressure drop from a flow, or a flow from a pressure drop. Models generally assume that either the across variables **or** the flow variable is determined by the outside. From that the model computes the other one using the relations defined in its `equation` section. For your example, all this comes down to: If you remove any equation, e.g. `a.Q = Q;` from the `Inlet`, the model checks. The explanation to this is how equations are generated from connectors and models. For more information on this see [Modelica Language Specification](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf), Section 9.2, bottom of page 110, saying "Each connection set is used to generate..."

Regarding both of the above points, I would recommend to take a look at the Modelica Standard Library's FluidHeatFlow library, especially the interface defined in `Modelica.Thermal.FluidHeatFlow.Interfaces.FlowPort`. Judging from your interface variables this library serves a similar physical domain.

For a simpler start it would also make sense to take a close look at `Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer`. This package only has a single pair of across/flow variables making it much easier to understand.

Comment: Is there a list that shows the couples of flow variables and across variables. As for the thermal fluid system, I am considering to use Pressure, Enthalpy, Mass flow in the definition of the connectors. The Pressure and Mass flow could be treated as a couple, but as for the Enthalpy, I am not sure which variable should be used together.

Comment: I think you should look into `Modelica.Fluid` which uses "stream connectors" for specific enthalpy. The learning curve might be a bit steep but it'll be worth the effort if you are going to work with thermofluid systems.

Comment: Some can also be found here:
https://mbe.modelica.university/components/connectors/simple_domains/ and especially for the fluid domain:
https://mbe.modelica.university/components/connectors/fluid_connectors/#fluid-connectors

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments I think you should look into Modelica's `stream connectors` which inherently support zero-flow and flow-reversal in thermofluid components.

They can be a bit tricky to understand so a while ago I put a small exemplary package on GitHub, demonstrating the very basics of stream connectors. If you're interested you can  find it here: https://github.com/justnielsen/ModelicaTutorials. There is also a [Wiki](https://github.com/justnielsen/ModelicaTutorials/wiki/Stream-connectors) page explaining the `Stream connector` syntax.

By the way, Claytex has an excellent [blog](https://www.claytex.com/blog/), updated weekly. They have a post from 2017 on stream connectors: https://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/fluid-connectors-modelica-standard-library/

Best regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: I am trying to refactor a modelica library, cause the connectors in this lib. don't use any flow variables and stream variables. If I plan to rewrite the code, is there any reference example?